# What governs that std::memset may be used if the destination object is trivially copyable and is not a potentially-overlapping subobject?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, memset

[Cppreference's page on `std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) states:

> #### `std::memset`
>
> ```
> // Defined in header <cstring>
> void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
> ```
>
> [...]  If the object is a potentially-overlapping subobject or is not
> *TriviallyCopyable* (e.g., scalar, C-compatible struct, or an array of trivially copyable type), the behavior is undefined.

What rules in the standard supports this claim?

Comment: I'm not sure the standard specifically mentions it in regards to `memset` but there is no requirement that `nullptr` has a bit pattern of `0`. As such if you `memset` any pointer (whole or as part of a struct or union) then the pointer value is implementation defined. Just accessing it can crash your program. `memset` on a C-compatible structure isn't even safe in C. So the set of types you can safely `memset` is a lot smaller in theory while in practice nullptr will almost always have a `0` bit pattern.

Comment: For the problems inherent with potentially-overlapping subobjects, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77848279/103167

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*(Self-answered as I think I found the complete answer during the progress of posting the question)*</sub>

---

[[cstring.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cstring.syn) Covers that we need to turn to the C standard library header `string.h` for the meaning of `std::memset`:

> ```
> namespace std {
>   // ...
>   void* memset(void* s, int c, size_t n);
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> /1 The contents and meaning of the header  are the same as
> the C standard library header <string.h>. [...]

E.g. the [C11 draft via N1570](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.1) specifies that the C standard library `memset` copies a byte (`unsigned char`) into the first `n` bytes of the destination object [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 7.24.6.1 The memset function
>
> **/1 Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **/2 Description**
>
> The memset function copies the value of c (**converted to an unsigned
> char**) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by
> s.
>
> **/3 Returns**
>
> The memset function returns the value of s.

Since this is the C standard "object" does not mean the same things as in C++; [Section 3.15p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15p1):

> **object** region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values

With this in mind, we go back to the C++ standard and [[basic.types]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#4), which tells us that the *object representation* of a (C++) object is the sequence of underlying `unsigned char` objects, and that for trivially copyable types, particularly, the *value representation* of the object is part of the object representation:

> The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T). [...] For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, **which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values**<sup>42</sup>.

with [the footnote 42](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types.general#footnote-42) clarifying the intent of this memory model representation allowing compatibility when interfacing with the C:

> The intent is that the memory model of C++ is compatible with that of ISO/IEC 9899 Programming Language C.

[[basic.types]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#3) expands on the effect of byte-wise copy of the underlying bytes from a source object to destination object (both of trivially copyable type), with an additional restriction that neither the source nor the destination object of such a byte-copy operation shall be a *potentially-overlapping subobject*:

> For any trivially copyable type T, if two pointers to T point to distinct T objects obj1 and obj2, where neither obj1 nor obj2 is a potentially-overlapping subobject, if the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up obj1 are copied into obj2,41 obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as obj1.

From this this is holds that `std::memset` may be used to set all (`n == sizeof(T)`) or a sub-set of (`n < sizeof(T)`) of the `unsigned char` objects in the underlying object representation of an object whose type is trivially copyable and where the object is not a potentially-overlapping subobject. The resulting value representation of the object is a discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values that the particular object represents. Note however that *reading* these values is not necessarily well-defined, one notorious example being using `std::memset` to set all the bits of a floating point to zero in a non-IEEE754-adhering implementation where "all bits zero" could represent a trap. Another thing to consider when using `std::memset` is that whilst it may create formally well-defined objects (in the standardese sense) their resulting values may violate class invariants.

Comment: _This means that copying the underlying bytes of such an object into the storage of another such object is sufficient for the other object to have the same value as the first object_ Not sure how you've managed to get to this conclusion. The value of an object is governed by http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#13.sentence-2. Assigning to bytes is not considered side-effect on an object to which they belong.

Comment: _the C11 draft via N1570 specifies that std::memset copies a byte (unsigned char) into the first n bytes of the destination object_ … _[basic.types]/4 tells us that the object representation of an object_ "object" in the C standard and "object" in the C++ standard are 2 different things. `memset` definition doesn't mean C++ objects.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks for the feedback! a) Is the problem w/ using "value" that it should be "value representation" instead, or is the conclusion entirely off? I'm curious then how to interpret "the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation _that determines a value_," b) How could we better find this connection between C standard and C++ standard? [\[basic.types\]/4/footnote42](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#footnote-42) mentions that "The intent is that the memory model of C++ is compatible with that of ISO/IEC 9899 Programming Language C.".

Comment: @LanguageLawyer As the OP of the question I'm most of all interested in an answer rather than attempting a self-answer: would you like to consider posting an answer to this question (I can remove my own attempt)? Or is the answer along the lines "the standard has some gaps/holes in this reasoning, but Cppreference's description correctly captures that actual state for most implementations"?

Comment: _would you like to consider posting an answer to this question_ I think the question is unanswerable. It "just works as [probably] intended" on existing implementations.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That's disheartening. In my own domain of safety critical C++ development it would basically mean we cannot use `std::memset`, as we can't make any formal promises on its behavior.

Comment: @dfrib: For safety-critical code, one should use a compiler that offers stronger behavioral guarantees than mandated by the Standard.  I don't know if there's a C++ equivalent to CompCertC, but there should be.  Optimizers that try to aggressively exploit places where the Standard imposes no requirements invariably fail to correctly handle all of the cases where the Standard does impose requirements, and would thus be unsuitable for safety-critical code regardless of what the Standard mandated.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Note that if one converts either of those pointers to a `uintptr_t` and then converts the result back to a pointer and attempts to use that to derive a pointer which is dereferenced, a conforming implementation could non-deterministically make the latter conversion yield whichever pointer would cause the program to invoke UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Further, both clang and gcc operate under an abstraction model where the act of observing that a pointer to one object is coincidentally equal to a pointer "just past" another is an invitation to behave nonsensically.  In clang's case, this principle applies even if code converts values to `uintptr_t`, multiplies them both by the same odd number, and compares the results.

Comment: @supercat _a conforming implementation could non-deterministically make the latter conversion yield whichever pointer would cause the program to invoke UB_ Not sure I've read this correct, but I think the standard doesn't allows this and says that roundtrip of a pointer value through integer cast should yield the same pointer value back. Which also means that the value of an integer is also not determined by bits in its value representation, because 2 `uintptr_t` with the same bit-pattern, but with different history, may behave differently when converting to a pointer

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: For the C Standard at least, the guarantee is that one gets a pointer that *compares equal* to the original.  Since the Standard expressly recognizes situations where two pointers may compare equal without being usable to access the same storage, the fact that a round-tripped pointer compares equal to the original in no way implies that it may be used interchangeably with the original.    While it would make sense to guarantee that implementations allow round-tripped pointer to be used interchangeably with any other pointer that, when converted, yielded the same number...

Comment: ...the Rationale's discussion of the One Program Rule makes clear that the authors of the Standard didn't want to impose any requirements that buggy compilers might not be able to meet.