# memcpy and potentially-overlapping subobject

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer

According to [basic.types#2] memcpy is not working for potentially-overlapping sub-objects.

> For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of
> trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid
> value of type T, the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up the
> object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or
> std​::​byte ([cstddef.syn]).36 If the content of that array is copied
> back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original
> value.

However to which extent is that?

For example, let's consider the example below. Is that legal to do? technically we are copying a potentially overlapping subobject to a different object, so the rule above shall not affect the code below.

```
    class Base { int i; };
    class Derived : public Base { int d; };
    
   void copy_base(const Base &src, Base &dest) {
      memcpy((void *)&dest, (const void *)&src, sizeof(Base));
   }

    
    int main() {
       Derived d;
       Base copy;
       copy_base(static_cast<Base&>(d), copy);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *However to which extent is that?*  It is to the extent of moving chunks of memory from one location to another location.  If those chunks of memory overlap, then undefined behavior results.

Comment: Side note :  The moment you need a "C" style void* cast (outside of type erasure) and call memcpy manually you missed an opportunity to use std::copy instead. I also think your code is just asking for trouble regardless of overlap anyway and this is not what overlap means. Overlap is when part of the memory you copy to is also part of the source memory you copy from.

Comment: `copy` is not a [potentially overlapping subobject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Size) of `static_cast<Base&>(d)`. There is a potential overlap between `d` and `static_cast<Base&>(d)`, but that's not what you're copying between.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `static_cast<Base&>(d)` obtains a potentially overlapping subobject, because every base subobject is a potentially overlapping subobject.  It's then not permitted to use raw memory access to the underlying representation, as `memcpy` does.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7.1

Comment: @BenVoigt but isn't this almost silly to be fair because Base is trivial and it is been copied into another object, even if Base sub-object got some padding in it from the Derived object, that would not matter since padding bits would be discarded.

Comment: @minex: memcpy doesn't know some of the bytes are padding, it copies exactly as many bytes as you tell it to.  (memcpy isn't even aware of the types of source and destination, both pointers are upcast to `void*` at the call site)

Comment: @BenVoigt but my point is that any padding won't affect object value representation so why padding matters here?

Comment: @minex: Read my answer, please

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, yes. The concept of "potentially overlapping subobject" is not with reference to another object. It's an absolute concept. I misinterpreted the wording. Thanks for calling me out.

Comment: Because you are copying between two _distinct_ object, the relevant rule is https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-3, not the one you quoted. But it also requires the source to not be potentially-overlapping.

Comment: @Peter: Completely incorrect.  This isn't about overlap between source and destination, and cannot be cured by `memmove`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the reason it is forbidden:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base
{
    short a;
private: // required to make Base NOT "standard layout"
    char b;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    
    printf("sizeof Base = %zd\n", sizeof (Base));
    printf("sizeof Derived = %zd\n", sizeof (Derived));

    Derived d;
    Base& b = d;
    const char* pb = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b);
    const char* pc = &d.c;
    printf("offset of c = %zd\n", pc-pb);
}
```

Output ([online demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3j4rr6bbd)):

> ```
> sizeof Base = 4
> sizeof Derived = 4
> offset of c = 3
> ```

Note that `Base` requires two-byte alignment, has three value bytes of representation and when it is a complete object it has one padding byte (to meet the alignment requirement).

```
  Base        Derived

---------    ---------
-       -    -       -
--  a  --    --  a  --
-       -    -       -
---------    ---------
-   b   -    -   b   -
---------    ---------
 padding     -   c   -
---------    ---------

 4 bytes      4 bytes
```

When `Base` is used as a base class, however, it doesn't receive the padding.  `Derived::c` is placed inside the location corresponding to  the padding of standalone `Base`.

If you blindly memcpy `sizeof Base` (4 bytes) from one `Base` instance into the `Base` subobject of a `Derived` instance, you'll trash the value of `c` in the destination.

Comment: yeah, that part is clear, but in my example, I don't copy Base into a Derived instance so your example does not apply here. Instead, I copy it in a completely different object which is Base, so basically I copy a potentially overlapping subobject into a NON-potentially overlapping one.

Comment: @minex: Correct: the prohibition in the Standard is a little bit broader than it needs to be.  It only needed to forbid "If the content is copied back into the object" and not the outgoing copy.  But as written, it forbids both.

Comment: @minex The copied bytes might not hold a valid object representation for the type of the target if it is potentially-overlapping. The compiler might make assumptions about the padding that might be violated.

Comment: @user17732522 that is correct, but the compiler can see that we are copying bytes into the independent object  **Base copy**, so that the value of **Base** won't be affected

Comment: @minex The padding bytes aren't part of the value representation of the independent target object, so its value can't be affected. However, the padding bytes in the independent target object can not otherwise be modified by the user, so the compiler can, with this constraint on `memcpy`, make assumptions about them (e.g. that they are always zero if the object doesn't have an indeterminate value). If you drop this constraint then such assumptions won't hold anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy()` simply copies bytes from one memory block to another memory block. If the destination block overlaps with the source block, this results in **undefined behavior**. You would need to use `memmove()` instead, which has well-defined behavior for copying overlapping memory blocks.

But, in your example, that is not the case, as you are copying bytes from one C++ object to a completely different C++ object, thus by definition they use different memory blocks and the overlap issue doesn't apply.

But, in any case, you shouldn't use `memcpy()`/`memmove()` to copy C++ objects in this manner to begin with. Doing so is **undefined behavior** for non-POD classes.

Just use normal object assignment instead, let the compiler figure out how to copy the source object into the destination object:

```
void copy_base(const Base &src, Base &dest) {
    //memcpy((void *)&dest, (const void *)&src, sizeof(Base));
    dest = src;
}
```

(which essentially renders your `copy_base()` function pretty useless, as you could just do `copy = d;` directly in `main()` instead)

---

Also, the `static_cast` on your call to `copy_base()` is unnecessary, as a derived object can be directly assigned to a reference to a base class:

```
//copy_base(static_cast<Base&>(d), copy);
copy_base(d, copy);
```

And, even if you do use `memcpy()`/`memmove()`, the `void*` casts are also unnecesary, as any memory pointer can be directly assigned to a `void*` pointer.

Comment: Isn't `memcpy` safe for trivially copyable types?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. It should be OK for POD classes.

Comment: The "potentially overlapping subobject" exclusion has nothing to do with source overlapping destination

Comment: still not completely clear on this as Base itself is trivially copyable, why memcpy is still not safe, given that it copies between different objects.

Comment: potentially overlapping is relevant eg for empty base class optimization cf. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Subobjects. Indeed its not about src overlapping dest, but about for example an empty base overlapping with something else.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Not necessarily an empty base.  See my answer.